# how can I use stored procedure with parameters in python code

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to use stored procedure in python code like below.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',
                      server = 'ZAMAN\SQLEXPRESS', database = 'foy3') 

def InsertUser(studentID,name,surname,birth,address,telephone):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("exec InserttoDB studentID,name,surname,birth,address,telephone")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I have a problem below part of code. How can I send function parametters to DB with InserttoDB (stored procedure)

```
cursor.execute("exec InserttoDB studentID,name,surname,birth,address,telephone")
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what database you are using but I think this should do the job.

```
cursor.execute("call SP_YOUR_SP_NAME(params)")
```